# Catch the loaded event of a Knockout component

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0, knockout-components

Is there a way to catch an event after a Knockout component is loaded and the viewModel is bound to a view?

I want to make custom popups using Knockout components and the popup should open only after loading is complete.

```
ko.components.loaders.unshift({
                getConfig: function (name, callback) {
                    var widgetName;
                    callback({ require: 'Popups/' + name });
                },
                loadViewModel: function (name, viewModelConfig, callback) {
                    var viewModelConstructor = function (params) {
                        var model = viewModelConfig(params);
                       //Some custom code
                        return model;
                    };
                    ko.components.defaultLoader.loadViewModel(name, viewModelConstructor, callback);
                }

            });
```

When Popup is opened

```
this.PopupModel.activePopup(popup);
ShowPopup(); // Makes popup visible.
```

Comment: please add some sample code to illustrate the issue and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: See [feature request](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1533)

Answer (score 1):

From version 3.5.0 you can use this: https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-lifecycle-events.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

There is a new event fired by registered components called `descendantsComplete`, added in the [this](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/2319) pull request. Description:

> Adds descendantsComplete event that is used by components to notify of completion, waiting until descendant components are also complete.

Usage:

```
<my-component data-bind="event: { descendantsComplete: doSomething() }">
</my-component>
```